# How to speed up tor

Tags: speed

I Had tried a lot of tricks from changing exit nodes or even bridges
but nothing works, keep in my mind that my ISP banned TOR so Relay system is so slow

Comment: If your ISP is throttling Tor, then have you tried using pluggable transports to stop the traffic looking like Tor traffic?

Answer (score 3):

With plenty of relays available on both sides of the Atlantic, you may find that a Tor circuit often forms picking relays on both sides, which adds to latency.

If you see countries on the opposite side you're on repeatedly coming up in circuits, you could use ExcludeNodes to exclude relays from those countries.

E.g.,

```
ExcludeNodes {US},{CA}
```

or

```
ExcludeNodes {FR},{DE}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume we don't want to sacrifice safety. Then the only options to seed up Tor (for everybody) are

- run a fast relay
- donate to organisations that run relays
- advertise running fast relays at ISPs, universities, wherever

If your ISP blocks or throttles traffic to the Tor network, that's really unrelated to speeding up Tor. That's exactly what Tor Bridges are there for. Just run/rent/use a Bridge Relay that is itself fast enough for you. Don't change Tor's relay path selection in any way other than using fast bridges.

You don't have to use pluggable transports like obfs3 or obfs4. Using a bridge relay your ISP doesn't know of should be enough.

Comment: nice, ok if i want to sacrifice my safety would it increase speed and how to do it !? I'm just surfing on blocked sites, not onion links so I don't do anything suspicious or danger

Comment: I don't find the config options for _allowing_ single-hop connections in tor's current documentation anymore, and I don't know if you can _force_ that at all, sorry. I personally would look at alternatives to Tor or do nothing and connect directly. That said, people have different views of what is suspicious. If you want to read the internet freely, use Tor.

Answer (score 0):

There are two factors that would contribute to how fast tor is for you;

1. The Speed of your internet connection.
2. The speed of the relays your tor connection is running through.

The main way for people to speed the tor network up would be for anybody who could, run a fast relay or fast bridge.

If your in software development, the tor source code is open source at least for the most part, so one COULD try to find ways to make the tor software run faster via source code, but if you were going to do that, make sure your not doing anything that could compromise the security.

If your ISP itself is throttling tor traffic, try using an obfuscated bridge.

Answer (score 0):

TOR will become faster only when everybody in the network or bridges use a real faster internet service. Anywhere in the loop a slower network results complete setup to go slow doesnot matter how the others perform. It is also To be noted TOR never faster if you using Mobile connection.